# fb-hydra: How to implement 2 nested structured configs?

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I have 2 sub configs and one master(?) config that having those sub configs. I designed configs like below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import MISSING, DictConfig

from typing import Any, List

@dataclass
class DBConfig:
    host: str = "localhost"
    driver: str = MISSING
    port: int = MISSING


@dataclass
class MySQLConfig(DBConfig):
    driver: str = "mysql"
    port: int = 3306


@dataclass
class PostGreSQLConfig(DBConfig):
    driver: str = "postgresql"
    port: int = 5432
    timeout: int = 10


@dataclass
class ConnectionConfig:
    target: str = "app.my_class.MyClass"
    params: DBConfig = MISSING
    defaults: List[Any] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: [
            {
                "params": "mysql",      # I'd like to set mysql as a default
            }
        ]
    )



@dataclass
class AConfig:
    name: str = "foo"


@dataclass
class BConfig(AConfig):
    age: int = 10


@dataclass
class CConfig(AConfig):
    age: int = 20


@dataclass
class SomeOtherConfig:
    target: str = "app.my_class.MyClass2"
    params: AConfig = MISSING
    defaults: List[Any] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: [
            {
                "params": "bconfig",   # I'd like to set bconfig as a default
            }
        ]
    )



@dataclass
class Config:
    db_connection: ConnectionConfig = ConnectionConfig()
    some_other: SomeOtherConfig = SomeOtherConfig()


@hydra.main(config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg.pretty())
    # connection = hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg)
    # print(connection)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cs = ConfigStore.instance()
    cs.store(
        name="config",
        node=Config,
    )
    cs.store(group="params", name="mysql", node=MySQLConfig)
    cs.store(group="params", name="postgresql", node=PostGreSQLConfig)

    cs.store(group="params", name="bconfig", node=BConfig)
    cs.store(group="params", name="cconfig", node=CConfig)

    my_app()
```

What I expected when I run program without any options:

```yaml
db_connection:
    target: app.my_class.MyClass
    params:   
        host: localhost
        driver: mysql
        port: 3306   

some_other:
    target: app.my_class.MyClass2
    params:
        name: "foo"
        age: 10
```

But the result:

```yaml
db_connection:
    target: app.my_class.MyClass
    params: ???
    defaults:
    - params: mysql
some_other:
    target: app.my_class.MyClass2
    params: ???
    defaults:
    - params: bconfig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as of Hydra 1.0 - the defaults list is ONLY supported in the [primary config](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/terminology#primary-config).
Below are two versions, the first version changes as little as possible in your example, and the second clean things up a bit.

#### Example 1:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import MISSING, DictConfig

from typing import Any, List


@dataclass
class DBConfig:
    host: str = "localhost"
    driver: str = MISSING
    port: int = MISSING


@dataclass
class MySQLConfig(DBConfig):
    driver: str = "mysql"
    port: int = 3306


@dataclass
class PostGreSQLConfig(DBConfig):
    driver: str = "postgresql"
    port: int = 5432
    timeout: int = 10


@dataclass
class ConnectionConfig:
    target: str = "app.my_class.MyClass"
    params: DBConfig = MISSING


@dataclass
class AConfig:
    name: str = "foo"


@dataclass
class BConfig(AConfig):
    age: int = 10


@dataclass
class CConfig(AConfig):
    age: int = 20


@dataclass
class SomeOtherConfig:
    target: str = "app.my_class.MyClass2"
    params: AConfig = MISSING


@dataclass
class Config:
    db_connection: ConnectionConfig = ConnectionConfig()
    some_other: SomeOtherConfig = SomeOtherConfig()
    defaults: List[Any] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: [
            {"db_connection/params": "mysql"},
            {"some_other/params": "bconfig"},
        ]
    )


@hydra.main(config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg.pretty())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cs = ConfigStore.instance()
    cs.store(
        name="config", node=Config,
    )
    cs.store(group="db_connection/params", name="mysql", node=MySQLConfig)
    cs.store(group="db_connection/params", name="postgresql", node=PostGreSQLConfig)

    cs.store(group="some_other/params", name="bconfig", node=BConfig)
    cs.store(group="some_other/params", name="cconfig", node=CConfig)

    my_app()
```

#### Example 2:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import MISSING, DictConfig
from hydra.types import ObjectConf
from typing import Any, List


@dataclass
class DBConfig:
    host: str = "localhost"
    driver: str = MISSING
    port: int = MISSING


@dataclass
class MySQLConfig(DBConfig):
    driver: str = "mysql"
    port: int = 3306


@dataclass
class PostGreSQLConfig(DBConfig):
    driver: str = "postgresql"
    port: int = 5432
    timeout: int = 10


@dataclass
class AConfig:
    name: str = "foo"


@dataclass
class BConfig(AConfig):
    age: int = 10


@dataclass
class CConfig(AConfig):
    age: int = 20


defaults = [{"db_connection": "mysql"}, {"some_other": "bconfig"}]


@dataclass
class Config:
    db_connection: ObjectConf = MISSING
    some_other: ObjectConf = MISSING
    defaults: List[Any] = field(default_factory=lambda: defaults)


cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="config", node=Config)
cs.store(
    group="db_connection",
    name="mysql",
    node=ObjectConf(target="MySQL", params=MySQLConfig),
)
cs.store(
    group="db_connection",
    name="postgresql",
    node=ObjectConf(target="PostgeSQL", params=PostGreSQLConfig),
)
cs.store(
    group="some_other",
    name="bconfig",
    node=ObjectConf(target="ClassB", params=BConfig()),
)
cs.store(
    group="some_other",
    name="cconfig",
    node=ObjectConf(target="ClassC", params=AConfig()),
)


@hydra.main(config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg.pretty())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

Comment: This really helps! Thanks

Comment: Your'e welcome.
We are working on improving the documentation of how to use instantiate with Structured Configs.

Comment: This is outdated as of Hydra 1.0.0rc4. Updated example: https://hydra.cc/docs/next/patterns/instantiate_objects/instantiate_with_structured_config

Comment: Your link is broken. Btw Omry, I love Hydra, great job :clap: !

Comment: Thanks!
Can't edit an old comment: here is a fixed link: https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/instantiate_objects/structured_config